# Custom old Android project structure in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

We have a project structure of the form

src
src_flavor1
src_flavor2
res
res_flavor1
res_flavor2


The core logic and resources are placed in src and res folder resp. The flavoured folders only contains few files which separate the two flavors.

 Im trying to define this project structure withing the build.gradle file but havnt found any success. Also Im trying to use the prductFlavor tags to create simultaneous builds of the two flavors but no success. Doing all this within the Android Studio latest build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have define your flavors like this:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        ...
    }
    flavor2 {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can modify the sourceSets of each flavor

```
android.sourceSets.flavor1 {
    java.srcDirs = ['src_flavor1']
    resources.srcDir = ['res_flavor1']
}

android.sourceSets.flavor2 {
    java.srcDirs = ['src_flavor2']
    resources.srcDir = ['res_flavor2']
}
```

I hope this help... (don't hesitate to add more details about your problems since it will help us to help you)

Last remark: according my experience, Android-Studio is not very stable *yet* and not full-featured *yet* regarding gradle<-->IDE sync. So I strongly suggest you to always test your gradle scripts from the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot ben for the reply. I will try this and get back to you. I do have few more things to clarify in this so i'll modify the question shortly

Comment: Thanks Ben it worked perfectly. Did a lot of permutations with src files and resources and all worked fine