# built flavors of a project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I want to build different flavors of a project (only the res folders have different contents), but it doesn't work.

So here is my build.gradle file (like in this question [Custom old Android project structure in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022773/custom-old-android-project-structure-in-gradle)):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project('<path>:actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }

            release{
            packageNameSuffix ".release"
            }

        android.sourceSets.flavor1 {
            res.srcDir = ['res_flavor1']
        }

        android.sourceSets.flavor2 {
            res.srcDir = ['res_flavor2']
        }

        productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
                packageName "androidstudio.test.flavor1"
            }
            flavor2 {
                packageName "androidstudio.test.flavor2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Structure of my folders (I want to change just one layout for each flavor):

```
my_project
    src
    res
    res_flavor1
    res_flavor2
```

I don't see any changes in the build variants, so when I export an apk its of the main directory (androidstudio.test).
Whats wrong with my file?

My Android Studio Version: 0.1.3.

If you need more information, say what and I will post it.
Thanks!

[**EDIT**]

@Greg:

I changed the res-folder in my question above, but I still get just two APKs in my project "out" folder (path: "out/production/androidstudio.test"): androidstudio.test.apk and androidstudio.test.unaligned.apk (the project and module name is: android.studio - I edited this names in my question above, otherwise its a bit confusing :)).

The different buildTypes should be generated automatically, shouldn't they? And to generate them I go to: Run -> Run "androidstudio.test".

I also looked in the log files of android-studio, but there is no error.

Here is a Screenshot of my Package Explorer, perhaps I made here a mistake?
[image]

I really don't understand why the flavors aren't build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be setting `res.srcDirs = ['res_flavor1']` instead of `resources.srcDir = ['res_flavor1']`. The naming is a bit confusing, but the "resources" directory isn't the same as the Android "res" directory.

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks for your comment. I edited my question above. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I solved my problem. My OS is Win7 (64bit) and I didn't set a JDK_HOME variable, so gradle did nothing...@Greg thanks for your help and sorry that I didn't notice the real problem :).